# After a picnic break or the picnic break?

Tags: articles, nouns

The context is the following:

We decided to have a picnic. After a picnic break we packed our bags and continued with our trip.

It seems to me that it should be:

After the picnic break and etc.

Answer (score 1):

i think this should be

> After the picnic break

you are talking about a precise event

Answer (score 1):

If you say “we decided to have a picnic”, you can no longer use “a”, because you already referred to the picnic you decided to have. If you omitted the first sentence “a” would sound fine. Otherwise use “the” or “that” or “this” to refer to the picnic that you have already made known.